# If a commander becomes a colorless forest, is it still a commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

In Magic the Gathering, I cast [Song of the Dryads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Song%20of%20the%20Dryads) on an opponent's commander. It is now a colorless forest land. My opponent has an [Angelic Field Marshal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Angelic%20Field%20Marshal) on the field which gains power if you control your commander. Is the colorless forest land still my opponent's commander? Does my opponent get the Lieutenant bonus?

Answer (score 4):

It is still your opponents commander and they will get the Lieutenant bonus from the Marshal. This is because being a commander is a property of a card, it doesn't matter if the characteristics of the card have changed at all it will still be their commander.

> **903.3.** Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.
>
> ***Example:** A commander that’s been turned face down (due to Ixidron’s effect, for example) is still a commander. A commander that’s copying another card (due to Cytoshape’s effect, for example) is still a commander. A permanent that’s copying a commander (such as a Body Double, for example, copying a commander in a player’s graveyard) is not a commander.*