# Can my commander ever not be my commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Once and for all: Is there anything that can possibly be done to my commander that would cause it to cease being my commander?

---

All of these questions ask the same thing, but aren't general enough to be marked as a duplicate.

- [If a commander becomes a colorless forest, is it still a commander?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/21055/6692)

  - **Is a commander still a commander if** it gets turned into a forest?
- [Is your commander still a "commander" if it gets turned face down?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/20772/6692)

  - **Is a commander still a commander if** it gets turned face down?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, 'commander-ness' is an intrinsic property of the card that nothing can take away.

> **903.3.** Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.
>
> ***Example:** A commander that’s been turned face down (due to Ixidron’s effect, for example) is still a commander. A commander that’s copying another card (due to Cytoshape’s effect, for example) is still a commander. A permanent that’s copying a commander (such as a Body Double, for example, copying a commander in a player’s graveyard) is not a commander.*